# Can I take non-direct flight on a type C Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas

I have a Schengen visa Type C valid for all Schengen countries. I have booked my flight to Germany but I have a transit in Paris. My flight is not direct to the country that issued my visa (Germany). Would that be a problem?

Comment: No problem. You're good!

Comment: @SheikPaul wouldn't that affect my future visa applications?

Comment: @JohnnyGhanem No

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no problem. You are supposed to apply at the country where you'll spend most of the time, in this case Germany. So if anything, the French may ask to see your onward ticket.